# PHP - Ensure array has certain number of items

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array which looks like this...

```
array
(
[0] => apple,
[1] => orange,
)
```

I need to ensure the array contains 4 items, so in the instance above I want to end up with this...

```
array
(
[0] => apple,
[1] => orange,
[2} => ,
[3] => ,
)
```

Am I best looping through this with a counter and creating a new array, or is there a better method?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php) your array with elements to a size that you need:

```
$my_arr = [1,2];
$my_arr = array_pad($my_arr, 4, '');
```

Comment: Would this work if I don't know the number of elements in the array?

Comment: Why not? You pad array to required size. Number of required elements will be counted as required size minus current size.

Comment: @fightstarr20 Yes. According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php) - _"...if the absolute value of size is less than or equal to the array length, no padding takes place."_ so it won't affect your array if the array already exceeds _4_ elements. It will only pad arrays with length `4 - count($my_arr) >= 1`...

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you're after

```
$iNumberOfElements = 5;

$a = array('apple', 'orange');

if(count($a) < $iNumberOfElements){
    while (count($a) < $iNumberOfElements) {
        $a[] = "";
    }
}

var_dump($a);
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

as @iainn said: php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php

there is this function:

```
$input = array(12, 10, 9);

$result = array_pad($input, 5, 0);
// result is array(12, 10, 9, 0, 0)
```

5 is the size of your array, 0 is the default value to empty cells